# How to Use Firebase Dynamic Link in Facebook App Install Ad?

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to create app install ads on Facebook for an App. I would like to track installs via Dynamic Links so I can see the effectiveness of each ad/campaign for user retention & various conversion events down the funnel.

With Facebook Ads, the only option for tracking is to add a dynamic link to the ad. However, the Firebase link is not a dynamic link, but a web link, so it isn't accepted by Facebook Ads.

I'm curious if others have had this problem and if there is a solution.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm generating firebase dynamic link on firebase console and when I try to put it in FB Ad's it gives me the same error" App Links Field Invalid:: The described URL doesn't have app links HTML meta tags. Use a different URL or a mobile deep link (eg 'mobileapp://). (#1487904)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this may not currently be possible.

At [Branch.io](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/support/ios/#use-a-direct-deep-link), we have a workaround for this by inputting a backup URI scheme link into the Facebook ad. But it appears the Firebase dynamic link does not have the required App Links tags set to support this method.

You may either need to rely on the Facebook console to track these, or use a different deep link provider.